# How do I take keyboard input in AutoIt?

Tags: autoit

I want to write a script in AutoIt, which can take automatic input from the keyboard, let's say A-Z, without user intervention.

Is this possible?

Comment: This question is way too unspecific to be answered.

Comment: It is still very hard to understand exactly what you are asking for. If you could give an example of what you want to do I'm sure I could be of more help. @Bombe while AutoIt wont replace Java for you it is amazing for Windows system automation tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unlikely that your program needs to capture all input from all keys. If you do in fact need that kind of user input AutoIt might not be for you - see [the post from the author of AutoIt about keyloggers](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=14632). If you need to take keyboard input of the hotkey type: doing that in AutoIt is super easy.

```
HotKeySet("^+{q}", "reactionFunction")

While 1
    ; A loop
WEnd

Func reactionFunction()
    MsgBox(0, "You pressed CTRL+Shift+q", "You pressed CTRL+Shift+q")
    Exit
EndFunc
```

If you want to take user input from an input box that is really easy also.

```
$data = InputBox("Enter Something", "Enter some data in the field below.")
MsgBox(0, "The String You Entered...", "The string you entered is... " & $data)
```

More information about HotKeySet and InputBox can be found in [the AutoIt.chm help file](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/) (it's actually a great reference).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your question - you want to *simulate* keypresses without someone actually using the keyboard?  If so, that's [the send command](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) in AutoIt.

You want to let a real user submit input to the script?  That's what [the GUI in AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/guiref/GUIRef.htm) is for.